# Less verbose way to remove objects from the same class in an array of multiple classes

Tags: java

Suppose I have an array with the following elements:

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
objects.add(1);
objects.add("one");
objects.add("two");
objects.add(new Object());
objects.add(2);
```

Is there a reduced way to remove certain objects of the same category?

For example, if I want to remove only the strings, I know I can do something like this:

```
for (Iterator<Object> it = objects.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
    if(it.next() instanceof String) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

But is this the minimal way to do it? I guess I can do it with `java-8` but I'm not too sure. Thanks!

Comment: Hm, `List#removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)` perhaps.

Comment: Why do you have objects of different types (`Integer`, `String`, `Object`) in the same list?

Comment: Yep, that gives off a bad code smell.

Comment: @MickMnemonic it's possibly just a poor example.  If the list is actually of some more specific supertype it's at least reasonable to want to do something to only some implementations.  E.g. remove all `LinkedList`s from a `List<List<E>>`.  I agree with you and Hovercraft about `List<Object>` being a red flag, though.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes, its just a bad example, is for a game, in my code I manage a general list (`List<Enemy>`) that contains all my enemies, and sometimes, I need to destroy only a certain type of them... Thanks!

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz, if this is the case, then perhaps it would make more sense to store your enemies in a data structure that allows grouping enemies by type, e.g. `Map<EnemyType, List<Enemy>>`, or better, [`Multimap<EnemyType, Enemy>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). This would make removing an enemy of a given type much simpler.

Comment: didn't know that, I'll gonna try it, thanks!

Comment: I figured this would be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. In the future, consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve in addition to how you're currently trying to solve it, and we can avoid similar exercises in futility. The solution by dimo is fine *theoretically*, but your best bet by *far* is to completely abandon this approach and go with the MultiMap or something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java 8 you can use [`Collection.removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
objects.removeIf(obj -> obj instanceof String);
```

It's still O(n), but it's a little more readable.

Comment: No problem, Java 8's a lot of fun :)